# How to display a value in a while loop only once but displaying the html the length of the loop

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a while loop that keeps track of two variables, incrementing them as the condition passes or fails. It is definitely incrementing them but it shows every iteration of the increment. I am only wanting to show the values once the while loop has finished. I know I need to close the loop and then display the value but I can't have that happen as I need the HTML to display multiple times for multiple users. I am wondering how to get the HTML to display multiple times but only have the two variables display for each user.

```
$addedItem = $tradedItem = 0;
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT adminid, log_operation FROM item_log_table WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '$time' and '$time2' ORDER BY adminid ASC";
$result = $db->prepare($sql);
$result->execute();
while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
    $username = $functions->getUserInfoSingularFromId('username', $row['adminid']);
    $lastLogin = $functions->getUserInfoSingularFromId('previous_visit', $row['adminid']);
    $lastLogin = $adminfunctions->displayDate($lastLogin);

    if ($row['log_operation'] == "ADDED ITEM") {
        $addedItem += 1;
    } else {
        $tradedItem += 1;
    } ?>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="border-radius: 16px; margin-top: 25px;">
            <div class="well profile col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center">
                    <p style="text-align:center;font-size: smaller;"><strong>Name | Employee: </strong><span class="tags" id="user-status"><?php echo $username; ?> | <?php echo $row['adminid']; ?></span></p>
                    <p style="text-align:center;font-size: smaller;"><strong>Date Last Logged In: </strong><span class="tags" id="user-status"> <?php echo $lastLogin; ?></span></p>

                    <div class="col-lg-6 left" style="text-align:center;overflow-wrap: break-word;">
                        <h4><p style="text-align: center;"><strong id="user-globe-rank"><?php echo $addedItem; ?></strong></p></h4>
                        <p><small class="label label-success">Items Added</small></p>                    
                     </div>
                     <div class=" col-lg-6 left" style="text-align:center;overflow-wrap: break-word;">
                         <h4><p style="text-align: center;"><strong id="user-college-rank"><?php echo $tradedItem; ?></strong></p></h4>
                         <p> <small class="label label-warning">Items Traded</small></p>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
<?php } ?>
```

[What it looks like in the loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1OpI.png)

I only want it to show the last iteration of the $addedItem and $tradedItem for each user. Also, excuse the style attributes I'm just prototyping.

Comment: Use an array keyed by admin id

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using DISTINCT you will only retrieve a single record for the `adminid` that has `log_operation` of `ADDED ITEM`.

For example if your table has:

```
| adminid | log_operation  |
| 1       |  ADDED ITEM    |
| 1       |  ADDED ITEM    |
| 1       |  TRANSFER ITEM |
| 2       |  ADDED ITEM    |
```

Your query would only retrieve

```
| adminid | log_operation  |
| 1       |  ADDED ITEM    |
| 1       |  TRANSFER ITEM |
| 2       |  ADDED ITEM    |
```

Resulting in `$addedItem` always equalling `1` for a specific adminid.
Since you're not resetting `$addedItem` per `adminid`, your loop will continue incrementing it for each `adminid`.

To resolve the issue and total all the `log_operations` that are `ADDED ITEM` for an `adminid` use aggregate functions on the desired `log_operation` value.

```
SELECT 
    adminid,
    SUM(CASE log_operation WHEN 'ADDED ITEM' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS addedItems,
    SUM(CASE log_operation WHEN 'ADDED ITEM' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS tradedItems
 FROM item_log_table
 WHERE `timestamp` BETWEEN '$time' AND '$time2'
 GROUP BY adminid
 ORDER BY adminid ASC
```

This will retrieve a single row for each adminid, with the total number of log operations that are `ADDED ITEM` and not.

### Example: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/muAESWHphmaBheZmf9wZWy/1

```
| adminid | addedItems | tradedItems |
| 1       |  2         | 1           |
| 2       |  1         | 0           |
```

Then just retrieve those columns in your html.

```
<div class="col-lg-6 left" style="text-align:center;overflow-wrap: break-word;">
    <h4><p style="text-align: center;"><strong id="user-globe-rank"><?php echo  $row['addedItems']; ?></strong></p></h4>
    <p><small class="label label-success">Items Added</small></p>                    
 </div>
 <div class=" col-lg-6 left" style="text-align:center;overflow-wrap: break-word;">
     <h4><p style="text-align: center;"><strong id="user-college-rank"><?php echo $row['tradedItems']; ?></strong></p></h4>
      <p> <small class="label label-warning">Items Traded</small></p>
 </div>
```

Comment: That looks what I need but I get this error. 

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '' AND '' GROUP BY adminid ORDER BY adminid ASC' at line 1 in /home/dh_5u3bz9/tradeflipsell.com/admin/audit.php:202 Stack trace: #0 /home/dh_5u3bz9/tradeflipsell.com/admin/audit.php(202): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in /home/dh_5u3bz9/tradeflipsell.com/admin/audit.php on line 202

Comment: @awild Updated, I left out the `FROM` portion of the query originally. `timestamp` is also a reserved word, so I escaped it with the backtick operator

Comment: @awild according to the error message `$time` and `$time2` are also empty.

Comment: I didn’t set an initial value for $time and $time2. I just get that from the form submission. Thanks for pointing that out. As far as testing the query I’ll have to do that later today as I am not home right now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @awild I added a fiddle link with the working query example to demonstrates that it works as expected. I added 0 and 10 for the time and time2. The query won't retrieve any results if `$time` and `$time2` are not set though, unless you remove the `WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '$time' AND '$time2'` criteria.